# Many items are displayed in the same position CSS grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I've got a massive list of nodes I'd like to display in a grid Layout.

At some point, more than 2500 items, less than 3500 items these boxes seem to collapse.

[image: collapsed Items]

I can't figure out what the problem is.

Is it the massive amount of divs? As my CSS works definitely fine for less than 2500 items.

That's the CSS, used for those boxes:

```
.products-group div.products-box{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 30% 30% 30%;
    column-gap: 5%;
    row-gap: 2em;
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.product{
    display: block;
    align-self: start;
}
```

That's my HTML:

```
<div class="products-group" data-group="{{group}}">
    
    <div class="controlls">
        <button class="drop">&#10507;</button>
        <h2>{{group}} ({{count}})</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="products-box">
        <div class="product hidden" data-sku="{{sku}}">
            <p>{{report}}</p>
            <button value="{{screenshot}}" onclick="show_picture(this)">Beweisbild</button>
        </div>

        ...

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you set `grid-auto-rows` to a fixed height (e.g.,`25px`), does the problem still occur?

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin yes it does.

Comment: Can't really assist you without being able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin I reproduced it with a little script, which spawns 3001 Elements in the same environment. it seems like the problem really is the amount of divs. The 3001st div is spawned in the position of the 2098th

Comment: Do you have the problem across browsers? Same output on Chrome, Firefox, Edge, Safari?

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin yes definitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like one of HTML, CSS or CSS-Grid is not able to display more then 3k child nodes.

The only way I saw, is to build a few more "products-box" divs and to display just 100 child divs in them.

```
<div class="products-group" data-group="{{group}}">
    
    <div class="controlls">
        <button class="drop">&#10507;</button>
        <h2>{{group}} ({{count}})</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="products-box">
        <div class="product hidden" data-sku="{{sku}}">
            <p>{{report}}</p>
            <button value="{{screenshot}}" onclick="show_picture(this)">Beweisbild</button>
        </div>
        <!--99 more-->
       
     </div>
</div>
```